# An unhandled exception has occurred in silverlight Application

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

I have SharePoint 2010 installed,
I am getting

> An unhandled exception has occurred in silverlight Application

when creating a list or site, what is causing this error and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved for me. Check by Control panel, Programs all the installed Silverlight programs.

If you installed **Silverlight 4**, then check for **Microsoft Silverlight** in control panel uninstall programs (Silverlight Developer runtime) by selecting the row

It would not be the version higher like 5.0.00.. (You can see on bottom status)

If so (5.0), uninstall **Microsoft Silverlight** (5.0 version)

Download from here

Silverlight 4 Developer Runtime v4.0.50524.0:

http://download.microsoft.com/download/C/5/8/C5877489-8022-42A6-8456-D05C2A6C8DFB/runtime/Silverlight_Developer.exe

and install it, then open your project. it will solve your problem.